# Sending message to WhatsApp using java

Tags: java, xmpp, sendmessage, whatsapp

Since I found some older posts, that tell that whatsapp doesn't support this, I was wondering if something had changed and if there is a way to open a whatsapp 'chat' with a number that I'm sending.
so which api will be useful to me??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have exactly the same question. I found out that it is not officially supported.

Some people are reverse engineering how whatsapp works and they created [an open source php library](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) and an open source [python library called yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) used by the [openwhatsapp](http://openwhatsapp.org/) application.

You will need a phone to use it and cannot use whatsapp on this phone anymore (may be solved by registering a whatsapp account on a cheap prepaid SIM).

Unless you want to port the PHP code to Java or reverse engineer yourself, I think the easiest way for Java is to make a private webserver that runs the PHP library. You could create a very small PHP script that simply calls the library with the receiver and text message as parameters and let Java call that library by posting to that private webpage.

I would like to know if others have better ideas and if there is a danger that Whatsapp decides to change how it works so that the open source libraries cannot be used anymore.

Comment: I found sniffing the password can be down with a .NET libray: github.com/shirioko/MissVenom but unfortunately whatsapp indeed changed how it works so that sniffing the password on Android is now impossible: github.com/shirioko/MissVenom/issues/7#issuecomment-23489710